# Is there an audioContext.encodeAudioData method?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In my program, I can take a .wav file and decode it into workable data. How do I encode it again to play the edited file?

Comment: `I can take a .wav file and decode it into workable data. How do I encode it again` it depends on how you "decoded" it. **Edit** it occurs to me you're referring to [`decodeAudioData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData). Just create a buffer source, assign the modified buffer to it, and connect it to the destination stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `encodeAudioData` method in WebAudio. Perhaps you can use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) or maybe wait for [web-codecs](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/blob/master/explainer.md) to be standardized and available in browsers.

Otherwise you'll have to write your own encoder.  A WAV file encoder is very, very simple.

Or if you simply want to play the decoded audio with WebAudio, [Patrick Robert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175805/is-there-an-audiocontext-encodeaudiodata-method/58176124#comment102732324_58175805) has the right idea.